# Is it advisable to add more brokers to kafka cluster although the load is still low

Tags: apache-kafka, configuration, cluster-computing

although we do not have any perfomance issues yet, and the nodes are pretty much idle, is it advisable to increase the number of kafka brokers (and zookeepers) from 3 to 5 immediately to improve cluster high availability? The intention is then of course to increase the replication factor from 3 to 5 as a default config for critical topics.

Comment: Note: you'll have to manually assign replicas/partitions to those new brokers

Comment: Thanks, I plan to use kafka-assigner from linkedin kafka-tools to do that, so that I am not worried about much manual work.

Comment: as long as you understand that your 5-node cluster will be slower than the 3-node you have now

Answer (score 1):

If high level of data replication is essential for your business, it is advisable to increase the count of brokers. To attain this, on top of extra nodes, you are creating a technical debt on network load also. Obviously if you increase the number of brokers in cluster, you are decreasing the risk related to loosing high availability.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your needs. If you do not have to ensure a very high availability(example a bank), the increase of replication factor in your cluster will reducer the overall performance because when you write a message on a topic/partition, that message will be replicated in 5 nodes instead of 3. You can increase the number of nodes for high availability and distribute less partitions on every node, but without a increase of replication factor.